# Google Compute Engine-Powered WordPress Site Hosted by Google Domains... How to Install SSL?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

It appears Google has some automated method of assigning SSL to App Engine products, but I simply have a Wordpress installation on Compute Engine, and nothing set up through App Engine.

My domain is hosted via Google Domain. I have connected the two, but the website is not set up with SSL as the URL has http not https.

Do I need to enable App Engine or is there a way to implement SSL certificate for my Compute Engine VM instance?

Apologies if the question is obtuse, the cloud environment is a bit more technical than I'm used to with webhosting.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stackoverflow. Is this is a Bitnami installation? To verify this go to Deployment Manager at your [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com) and share with us the deployment type. If the deployment says something about BITNAMI you are very lucky and the process is quite simple and fully automated, but if not, the process may take more extra steps.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately it is not. It's the Google Click-to-Deploy (I foolishly assumed this would be the most simple based on the name) and it's the Wordpress Multisite implementation.

Comment: You can attach a Google HTTPS Load Balancer in front of your instance. Google then manages SSL for you. This provides lots of benefits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use App Engine in this case and you have at least two solutions:

**Solution 1**

You can [set up Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl/setting-up-ssl) for your Wordpress site - which in my opinion is the most "painless" and simple. You also don't have to worry about SSL certificate itself (you will get one and will be renewed automatically).

- [create an unmanaged instance group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-unmanaged-instances) and include your VM running Wordpress site
- [reserve an IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) for yor load balancer
- create load balancer with [backend service](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service) (create new service with your instance group - it's one of the steps when creating LB)
- while creating front end for the LB select [Google Manged Certificate](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs)

Now you have to direct your domain to be resolved to the new IP (you just reserved).

**Solution 2**

Obtain your own SSL certificate - you can get one from [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).
From the way you deployed your site means you're running Debian 9 with Apache2 webserver.
You can find [specific instructions for that scenario here](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/debianstretch-apache) (official Certbot documentation).
It's a lot more hassle and it's much harder to do than first solution.
You can also find [detailed instructions here](https://onepagezen.com/free-ssl-certificate-wordpress-google-cloud-click-to-deploy/).

**----------------- U P D A T E ----------------**

How to create GCP HTTPS Load Balancer using Console:

- goto Network Services > [Load Balancing](https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/loadbalancing/loadBalancers/list) and click "Create load balancer"; select "HTTP(S) Load Balancing,
- select "From Internet to mmy VMs" ahnd click continue
- `name` - pick anything you like;
- `backend configuration` - create new one:
  [image]
- name your service anyway you like (for example wordpress-lb),
- `backend type` - select instance group
- `port` - select HTTPS - change its name to `https` just for more clarity
- in the "New backedn" window select your instance group and put in 80 in the "port number" field; no need to change other options and click "done" button.
- `health check` - select "create new health check" - put any name you like; no need to touch anything else; click "Save & continue"
- your service is ready - click "Create" button on the bottom.
- click on Host and path rules (just for a review)
- click "Frontend configuration" - put in an name, select HTTPS protocol
- select your IP you reserved earlier - it will be on the list (unless it's used by some other services)
- select port 443
- select certificate - if you don't have any create one or upload it:
  [image]
- now click "create" to create new load balancer and wait a while. Sometimes it takes a few minutes to all services to spin up.

If you want more detailed explanation for creating load balancer in GCP please have a look at [this tutorial on GeekFlare](https://geekflare.com/gcp-load-balancer/).

Comment: Thanks, but the step 3 is extremely confusing and doesn't have a clear set of instructions. Can you provide some clarification on exactly how I would create a load balancer as needed? I don't see any steps to take on that page, just a huge amount of information for IT type people (which I am not...)

Comment: I updated my answer with more details on creating GCP Load Balancer - hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, very detailed and helpful.

Comment: Hi there, just a kind reminder that Solution 2 is better than 1 for individuals because 1 will cost you around US$18/month. Actually, the setting in Solution 2 is pretty simple if your system is Linux like Ubuntu.